# Implementing a Jquery counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm very new to web development and am trying to implement a counter that increases when an item is selected, but also decreases if the selected item is unselected. 
I have the counter increasing when the item is selected but cant seem to get the counter to go down when the item is unselected (it still counts up)
the code i have is below(excuse how bad it is like i say I'm new to this)

```
//highlights current selection and alows a choice of 4 seats to be made
//need to implement unselecting a seat
$('td.n').click(function(){
  if(checkcounter())
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
    $('#seatsAlloc').text(SeatAlloc.toString());    
  }  
});

//cycles through all the seats to check if they are taken or available
//adds taken class to all taken seats
for(x=0;x<=139;x++)
{
    if (d.alloc[x] == 1)
    {
      $($('td.n')[x]).addClass('taken');
    }
}

var SeatAlloc = 0;
var Seat_Counter = 0;
function checkcounter()
{
  if(Seat_Counter < 4)
  {
    Seat_Counter++;
    SeatAlloc++;
    return true;
  }
    Seat_Counter--;
    SeatAlloc--;
    return false;
}
```

If anyone has any help it would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks!

Comment: Try using an else-if within your `check counter()` function for the decrementing?

Comment: Could it be that you're just missing an `else { ... }` around the decrement part of your `checkcounter()` function?

Comment: where you declare this ( d ) object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('td.n').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
  $('#seatsAlloc').text($('td.selected').length);    
});
```

This code either removes or adds the class 'selected' to the pressed td and after that it simply counts the amount of td's with the class 'selected'.

Yes it can be that simple.

So if you want max 4 seats selected you can do following.

```
    $('td.n').click(function(){
      var amountSelected = $('td.selected').length;
      if(amountSelected <= 4) {
          $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
          $('#seatsAlloc').text($('td.selected').length); 
      }   
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't count down like the op wants

Comment: i have edited my answer, it works; if it doesnt please provide your HTML code

Comment: This is just what I was looking for thank you although on the first click it increments by 2 is there a way around this?

Comment: Thats odd, should be because one TD is selected by default. Test is out in the console (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and type : $('td.n') and check the result

Comment: @PatrickAleman once I've typed it into the console what am I looking for? this is the only thing that isnt 0 on load, ***childElementCount: 1*** none of  the TD elements are selected.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?